# In Excel 2013 compare data from multiple columns and highlight values if different using macro and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code I found on this sight which is extremely close to what I want. It essentially highlights values that do not match to a list of values found in another tab. The addition I would like to make to this code is to continue the search across multiple columns.

For this particular example, I would like the code to change each "U" and each "A" to "V" and "B" respectively, (essentially moving right to the next column for each sheet) until there is a blank column.

```
Sub CompareAndHighlight()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To Sheets("workorders").Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = Sheets("workorders").Range("U" & i)
        For j = 1 To Sheets("craftspersondata").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng2 = Sheets("craftspersondata").Range("A" & j)
            If StrComp(Trim(rng1.Text), Trim(rng2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                rng1.Value = "Incorrect Name"

            End If

            Set rng2 = Nothing
        Next j
        Set rng1 = Nothing
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't this code highlight everything in ColU which *matches* anything in ColA ?  StrComp=0 means a match....

Comment: Yes, I was simply posting the closest example of the code I would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to replace each occurrence of "U" to "A" & each "V" to "B", inside a given range, wouldn't a find-replace work better? Simpler, quicker, cleaner. Ex:

```
Range(<insert range>).Replace What:="V", Replacement:="B", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
Range(<insert range>).Replace What:="U", Replacement:="A", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

If you want the replace to be case sensitive just replace `MatchCase:=False` with `MatchCase:=True`, and if you only want it to replace if the entire contents of the cell are "U" or "V", then replace `LookAt:=xlPart` with `LookAt:=xlWhole`

The only reason the iteration made sense in the example code you cite is that the individual that wrote that not only wanted to replace the value, but also to alter the fill color for the cell `rng1`